# How to use item selected from spinner

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I have a spinner. I populated it with  data(of one column) from a database table. Now when a user select an item from spinner. I want a function in database which returns corresponding primary key of the selected item. In my main activity that primary key should be stored in a variable. How can I do this.

This is my code in main activity:

```
if(spinner.getSelectedItem() != null){
    spinner_text = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    try {
        substation_number = myDB.spinnerResult(spinner_text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is my function in database:

```
public int spinnerResult(String item_name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select substationNo from " + TABLE_NAME + " where item_name = ?", new String[]{item_name});
    return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cursor));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cursor you get by `rawQuery()` should return at most 1 row (if `item_name` is unique in the table) with 1 column.
You must check with `moveToFirst()` if the `item_name` you passed exists in the table and then extract the value of `substationNo` from the cursor:

```
public int spinnerResult(String item_name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select substationNo from " + TABLE_NAME + " where item_name = ?", new String[]{item_name});
    int result = 0; // you may change this
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) result = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

If the `item_name` you passed does not exist in the table the function returns `0` which you may change to `-1` if you want and you can check it to verify that the `item_name` was found.